# raven celery client logs are not showing up on sentry server

Tags: celery, sentry, raven

I'm upgrading raven to 2.0.3, but can not see any logs make it through onto the server. I've patched raven so that I can use celery: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/commit/1be659a1eba721a29ca889e632538ddd459c4acf.

The SENTRY_DSN must be getting picked up, because when I change it celery is showing 403 responses (forbidden from the server). The tasks are getting picked up by celery because I can see tasks being completed successfully in the logs:

```
[2012-08-06 13:28:20,885: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: raven.contrib.django.celery.send_raw[f58d441c-713b-4d90-9a75-fcdaf753cd5b]
[2012-08-06 13:28:21,061: INFO/PoolWorker-1] Configuring Raven for host: http://xxxxxx@xxxx.dotcloud.com:/2
[2012-08-06 13:28:22,025: INFO/MainProcess] Task raven.contrib.django.celery.send_raw[f58d441c-713b-4d90-9a75-fcdaf753cd5b] succeeded in 0.966000080109s: None
```

However, I can not see any events on the sentry server. Server side I have:

```
Django==1.4.1
django-celery==3.0.4
raven==2.0.3
sentry==4.8.6
celery==3.0.5
```

Is there some setting that is missing?

Comment: I changed the config around to eliminate the dependency on celery. Raven on the client now uses the normal Django client (not the celery client), but the events still don't appear on the server. I can see in the logs on the server that when the log call is made (log.error("message")) that the Raven client is set up with a DSN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that my logging setup was most probably causing some sort of race condition, which meant that Raven would print that it was sending logs, but never actually got around it.

Fixed by setting CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS = False

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/celery-users/6_Suz2tscMQ